# how to get the reference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

please help solve the problem.

There is a table users:

```
id :integer, autoincrement
name :string
gender_id :integer
```

There is a table genders:

```
id :integer, autoincrement
gender_name :string
```

model User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :gender
end
```

model Gender:

```
class Gender < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :users
end
```

I need the gendername. I try to do so:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <div class="col-xs-6"><%= user.name %></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"><%= user.gender_id %></div>
<% end %>
```

the result is output number, but I need to gendername

Comment: Have you tried `user.gender.gender` (and in light of that calling the property `name` instead of `gender` for more readability)?

Comment: i get follow error message:
undefined method `gender' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I don't know if this is causing the problem, but in the `Gender` class it should be: `has_many :users` (note the "s" on users). According to the associations you've specified, `user.gender.gender` should give you that `String` property on the `Gender` class.

Comment: In your last edit you incorrectly added an "s" to the belongs_to relation. Think about how users and genders are related: A gender has many users, but a user has only ONE gender. So in the User class you want `belongs_to :gender` and in the Gender class you want `has_many :users` (notice that one is singular and the other is plural).

Answer (score 0):

my column 'gender_id' contain zero value. This problem has been